# Sum and dump operation

Tags: filtering, signal-processing

I've looked a different Mathematica functions, and I don't find the following: sum and dump. It would be:

```
data = {1.,2.,3.,4.,5.,6.};

sumAndDump = {1.+2.,3.+4.,5.+6.};
```

etc.

What I find is operations that move over 1 element, but don't do a separate calculation for each group of sub-elements.

Of course, this could be programmed with a `Do` loop, but I was wondering if there was a more direct method. Thank you.

Comment: `BlockMap[Total, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, 2]`. `Plus @@@ Partition[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, 2]`.

Comment: BlockMap!? One more reason being stuck at 10.0 is terrible.

Comment: `Downsample[2 MovingAverage[data, 2], 2]`

Comment: Thank you! At first I didn't realize those were two separate methods! BlockMap seems robust to an incomplete ending, e.g. BlockMap[Total, {1.,2.,3.,4.,5.},2] works OK also. It just ignores the incomplete sub-list.

Answer (score 2):

I don't want to see this closed as "easily found in the documentation", because it isn't. So it needs a formal answer, which I am providing.

Szolbolcs approach using [`BlockMap`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BlockMap.html)

```
BlockMap[Total, Range[6], 2]
```

> `{3, 7, 11}`

which was introduced in V10.2 seems to be best. For one thing it is tolerant of ragged final elements in the underlying partition.

```
BlockMap[Total, Range[7], 2]
```

> `{3, 7, 11}`

For other, it is very efficient because it does't actually perform the partition. (The documentation article says "[does] not construct all the sublists and requires less memory [than other methods]".)